# How can one test their 1gbps server connection via ssh?

Tags: ssh, internet-speed

My ubuntu server has a 1gbps connection. How can I test this connection via ssh terminal?

Comment: scp would be a start.

Answer (score 2):

For a general command line Internet speed test, you could use [speedtest-cli](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli).

One-liner usage:

```
python3 <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py)
```

<sup><sub>**Note:** The above command assumes that you trust the Python 3 code retrieved from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py.</sub></sup>

Sample output:

```
deltik@box1 [~]$ python3 <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py) --server 17394
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from OVH Hosting (167.114.208.99)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Retrieving information for the selected server...
Hosted by Bell Canada (Toronto, ON) [3.18 km]: 19.545 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 2366.49 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 689.48 Mbit/s
```

---

If you want to test the speed between your server and a client that you control, you can use [iPerf3](https://iperf.fr/).

First, install iPerf3 on both the client and the server.  Ubuntu/Debian installation command:

```
sudo apt install -y iperf3
```

On the server, run `iperf3` in server mode:

```
iperf3 -s
```

On the client, run one of these commands to test the speed:

<sup><sub>(Replace `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` with your server's IP address.)</sub></sup>

- Client to server TCP transfer:

  ```
  iperf3 -c XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  ```
- Server to client TCP transfer:

  ```
  iperf3 -R -c XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  ```